# Python string to two dimensionals list

Tags: python, list, flask

i have string like below :

```
FuntionStr='AccName,S,Balance,N,AccrInterest,N'
```

i would like to convert string to two dimensionals list :

```
FuntionList=[('AccName','S'),('Balance','N'),('AccrInterest','N')]
```

Please help give me any example code.

Regards,

Comment: That's not a two dimensional list, is a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output is a list of tuples which you can get with `zip`, `str.split` and using `iter` which is more efficient than slicing.

```
FuntionStr='AccName,S,Balance,N,AccrInterest,N'
it = iter(FuntionStr.split(","))

print(list(zip(it,it)))
[('AccName', 'S'), ('Balance', 'N'), ('AccrInterest', 'N')]
```

If you have an uneven length list after splitting and you don't want to lose any data you can use `zip_longest`:

```
FuntionStr='AccName,S,Balance,N,AccrInterest,N,foo'
it = iter(FuntionStr.split(","))
from itertools import zip_longest
print(list(zip_longest(it, it,fillvalue="")))]
('AccName', 'S'), ('Balance', 'N'), ('AccrInterest', 'N'), ('foo', '')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. it's help me full.

Comment: @RimSovankiry, no worries, what happens if the strings are not even?

Comment: wow it's cool to return [] .if a string is blank.

Comment: I cannot import zip_longest in itertools.

Comment: my python 2.7 doesn't have zip_longest.

Comment: @RimSovankiry, it is `izip_longest` in python2

Comment: Thank you  @Padraic Cunningham.

Answer (score 1):

To get this:

```
FuntionStr='AccName,S,Balance,N,AccrInterest,N'
my_list = FuntionStr.split(',')
print my_list
print zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('AccName','S'),('Balance','N'),('AccrInterest','N')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
temp = FuntionStr.split(',')
>>>zip(temp[::2], temp[1::2])
[('AccName', 'S'), ('Balance', 'N'), ('AccrInterest', 'N')]
```